# My AnimationDrawable object's run method slows down my application, any solutions?

Tags: java, android, animation, animationdrawable

I am writing a basic Android app. I did create an AnimationDrawable object to display my multiple images in my layout and set it. After that, my application started to slow down. And i even tried to work that code block on new thread but it didn't work as i imagined. What did I do wrong? or Is there any solution to that? Thanks in advance.

I'm calling this method on my onCreate() method;

```
/*
 * This method configures the background animation
 * */
private void configureAnimation(){
    animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    for (int i = 0; i < bgImage.length; i++) {
        animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(bgImage[i]), 5000);
    }
    animation.setEnterFadeDuration(1000);
    animation.setOneShot(false);

    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mLayout);
    linearLayout.setBackground(animation);

    animation.start();
}
```

Whole Class;

```
package com.example.yekta.loginapp;

import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private LinearLayout linearLayout;
    private AnimationDrawable animation;
    private int []bgImage = {R.drawable.wallpaper00, R.drawable.wallpaper01};

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.placeholder_fragment, new LoginFragment());
        ft.commit();

        hideActionBar();
        changeStatusBarColor(R.color.black);

        // First Approach
        //configureAnimation();

        // Second Approach with using Thread
        //startProgress();

        // Third Approach
        animation = new AnimationDrawable();
        handleAnimation(100,animation);
        animation.start();
    }


    /*
    * This is simple method that changes the color of status bar.
    * @param colorCode is the color code that given in value file
    * */
    private void changeStatusBarColor(final int colorCode) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            Window window = this.getWindow();
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, colorCode));
        }
    }

    /*
     * This is simple method that hides the Action bar.
     * */
    private void hideActionBar(){
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.hide();
    }

    /*
     * This method configures the background animation
     * */
    private void configureAnimation(){
        animation = new AnimationDrawable();
        for (int i = 0; i < bgImage.length; i++) {
            animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(bgImage[i]), 5000);
        }
        animation.setEnterFadeDuration(1000);
        animation.setOneShot(false);

        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mLayout);
        linearLayout.setBackground(animation);

        animation.start();
    }

    public void startProgress() {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                configureAnimation();
            }
        });
    }

    private void handleAnimation(final int time, final AnimationDrawable animation) {
        Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < bgImage.length; i++) {
                    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(bgImage[i]), 5000);
                }
                animation.setEnterFadeDuration(1000);
                animation.setOneShot(false);
                linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mLayout);
                linearLayout.setBackground(animation);
            }
        }, time);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the value of `bgImage.length`? and also how big the background images are

Comment: @Lino There are only two images in that array at the moment so it is 2, right now.

Comment: Let me see, you want to make a splash screen animation before the login screen ?, Please remove the animation.start() from OnCreate

Answer (score 0):

I think it is safer to call it onResume(), if you start the animation on OnCreate() you will probably get ANR, and you could try this approach:

```
animation = new AnimationDrawable();          
animation.start();
handleAnimation(100,animation);

private void handleAnimation(final int time, final AnimationDrawable animationDrawable) {
         Handler handler = new Handler();
         handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
               @Override
                public void run() {
               for (int i = 0; i < bgImage.length; i++) {
                    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(bgImage[i]), 5000);
              }
               animation.setEnterFadeDuration(1000);
               animation.setOneShot(false)
               linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mLayout);
               linearLayout.setBackground(animation);
             }
           }, time);
        }
```

Comment: Still the same. I even tried to switch animation.start() line and handleAnimation() implementation line between them. But UI still runs considerably slow.

Comment: Can you post the complete class ?

Answer (score 0):

I find my own problem :D. And that was a stupid problem which based on asset plugin that I installed to Android Studio, Android Drawable Importer. Problem is image was so huge to load to HD Screen Emulator so it slowed down the application naturally. When I configure it to normal sizes that as it should be, it solved my problem. I am so sorry to take your time :D. Thank you to everyone who tried to help me out. Happy coding everyone.